# R - Converting NA to specific date within a date column

Tags: r, date

I am new to R, and I have this data frame where one of my column has dates. It represents end dates, so whenever there is no end, there is NA, which thus means "ongoing". Lets say I am considering my datalock to be 2016-11-01, then I would like the NAs to turn into "2016-11-01". The reason why I want a date and not NA is because I want to make calculation out those data, and NAs introduce a bias in my final result. I red anything I could and multiple attempt based on those reading failed. I am sure it is some basic stuff I am currently blind to.

**dput is:**

```
structure(list(traitm.start = structure(c(14039, 12410, 14495, 
14378, 13238, 13859, 14732, 12762, 13853, 12675, 12784, 16465, 
13958, 14155, 14123, 13860, 13055, 12809, 14822, 14816, 12476, 
13081, 14183, 12475, 14560, 15026, 15006, 16514, 13993, 13963, 
13257, 14173, 13013, 15435, 14463, 14999, 13480, 13915, 14536, 
14904, 16865, 16436), class = "Date"), traitm.stop = structure(c(15908, 
13633, 16733, 15078, NA, 14473, 15719, 12802, 14236, 12695, 16988, 
NA, 14030, 15587, 15083, NA, 13584, 13634, NA, 15084, 12869, 
15772, 16071, 12481, 16534, 15400, NA, 16863, 14781, 15198, 13390, 
14963, 14426, 16988, 16289, 15405, NA, 14728, 15980, 15155, NA, 
16841), class = "Date"), IS.rlp = c("1", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", 
"0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0"), treat.lenght = structure(c(62, 
41, 75, 23, NA, 20, 33, 1, 13, 1, 140, NA, 2, 48, 32, NA, 18, 
28, NA, 9, 13, 90, 63, 0, 66, 12, NA, 12, 26, 41, 4, 26, 47, 
52, 61, 14, NA, 27, 48, 8, NA, 14), class = "difftime", units = "days")), .Names = c("traitm.start", 
"traitm.stop", "IS.rlp", "treat.lenght"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L
), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is where I am stuck, with two problems:

using dplyr:

```
HMRoo2_Allo_M4 <- HMRoo2_Allo_M4%>%mutate(traitm.stop=
     ifelse(is.na(HMRoo2_Allo_M4$traitm.stop) ==TRUE,
     2016-11-01,HMRoo2_Allo_M4$traitm.stop))
```

1) how to tell R that `2016-11-01` has to be a date? 
2) In the final product, all the dates are turned into their internal numeric form. From there, I am struggling to get them back to date format.

Thank for your help

Comment: If your `treat.length` variable is meant to be days from `traitm.start`to `traitm.stop` I don't think you're getting the right numbers there.

Comment: you are right, there are not days, there are months (which the calculation I aimed at)

Comment: Added code in answer for month calculation. Feel free to accept if it meets your requirements

Comment: To convert the numerics to date, use `as.Date(HMRoo2_Allo_M4$traitm.stop, origin = Sys.Date() - <NANumericValue>)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code chunk is a mess so I'm not going to read it.Here's how you can set the whole column to a date. Let df be the data.frame, and date be the date column.

```
df$date = as.Date(as.character(df$date),"%Y-%m-%d)
```

This is how you would set the NA entries to a specific date. Assuming you want to convert to 12/31/9999. Swap this out with whatever date you want.

```
df$date[is.na(df$date)] = as.Date("12-31-9999","%m-%d-%Y)
```

Comment: I agree with you, the code is no pretty, it was the only code that did execute though, without error message. Probably the accumulation of a lot of mistakes. Your code works for me, I can not believe it!! I have try this same type of code over and over, it wouldn't work before. Many thanks for your input.

Comment: @Sevland No problem! Glad to help. Please mark it as answered.

Comment: @Sevland Also, if you tried similar code and it did not convert it's possible that your date column got converted to a factor. Running as.Date() on a factor won't do anything. I've run into that issue a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` makes it look easy. First, basic setup:

```
install.packages("data.table") #optional, run if you don't have data.table package
library(data.table)
```

The operations you need:

```
setDT(df)   #turn into data.table
df[is.na(traitm.stop), traitm.stop := as.Date('2016-11-01')]
setDF(df)  #optional, turn back to Data.frame
```

Notes:

> The data.table formula is DT[I,J,by] -- I is the subset or join, J is the operation to be performed, by is the grouping element. In our case, I is the `is.na` function on the `traitm.stop`. It returns a boolean of the same length as your data.table, allowing you to efficiently subset. J is the operation on `traitm.stop` where `:=` is an assign operator special for data.tables. `as.Date` tells R that the string `2016-11-01` is a date. There is no `by`, since we are working on the full data set.
>
> `SetDT` is an in-place (no copy) operator that turns a data.frame into a data.table. `SetDF` turns the data.table back into a data.frame, since most users who are not familiar with data.table will have trouble using its syntax.

Results:

```
   traitm.start traitm.stop IS.rlp treat.lenght
 1:   2008-06-09  2013-07-22      1      62 days
 2:   2003-12-24  2007-04-30      0      41 days
 3:   2009-09-08  2015-10-25      0      75 days
 4:   2009-05-14  2011-04-14      1      23 days
 5:   2006-03-31  2016-11-01      1      NA days
 6:   2007-12-12  2009-08-17      1      20 days
 7:   2010-05-03  2013-01-14      1      33 days
 ...
```

PS: For correct months between calculation:

```
library(mondate)
df[, treat.length := MonthsBetween(mondate(traitm.stop),  mondate(traitm.start))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, and the explanations. Priceless to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify `NA`'s

`whereToAdd <- is.na(HMRoo2_Allo_M4$traitm.stop)`

2. Insert into column where `NA`

`HMRoo2_Allo_M4$traitm.stop[whereToAdd] <- as.Date("2016-11-01")`

OR all in one

```
HMRo2_Alo_M4[is.na(HMRo2_Alo_M4$traitm.stop), ] <- as.Date("2016-11-01")
```